# Accessing multiple SQL databases with the same schema

Tags: sql, sql-server, database

I am creating a new SQL database that needs to connect to several existing DB's, all of which have the same schema.

I would like to create stored procedures that can be used to access any of the existing DB's whilst re-using code as much as possible. My question is, what is the best way to write generic SP's that can be used to access any one of these existing databases?

Here are some options I have considered so far. Please note, these are just simple code snippets to illustrate the question, not real-world code. First I tried switching on the DB name:

```
IF @db = 'A' 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM A.dbo.SERIES_DATA
END
IF @db = 'B' 
BEGIN
    SELECT * FROM B.dbo.SERIES_DATA
END
```

This has the disadvantage that the same SQL statement is repeated several times. So then I thought of using dynamic SQL:

```
DECLARE @Command varchar(100)
SET @Command = 'select * from ' + @db + '.dbo.SERIES_DATA'
EXEC (@Command)
```

This solves the problem of duplicate staements, but has the risks of dynamic SQL (e.g. injection attacks etc). So finally I hit on the idea of creating a Table-valued Function:

```
CREATE FUNCTION [dbo].[ufnSeries_Data] (@db varchar(10))
RETURNS TABLE 
AS
RETURN (
    SELECT * FROM A.dbo.Series_Data WHERE @db = 'A'
    UNION
    SELECT * FROM B.dbo.Series_Data WHERE @db = 'B'
)
GO
```

This gives me the ability to write single, generic code to access any of the DB's:

```
SELECT * FROM ufnSeries_Data(@db)
```

The problem with *this* approach is that I have to give **all** users of the system read-access to **all** of the databases in order for this query to work, otherwise I get an access-denied error. I'm also not certain of the performance impact of creating a TVF like this.

Does anyone has any other ideas for how I can structure my code to minimize duplication of statements? Maybe there is a much simpler approach that I'm missing? I would be very grateful for any suggestions.

Comment: Are you able to write a `VIEW` that does the concatenation and let the sprocs consult that view?

Comment: You should be able to solve the permission problem using [`EXECUTE AS`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188354.aspx), however I can't speak for the performance impact part.

Comment: View is a better option than TVF

Comment: @adrianm Won't a view by design query all databases, while the TVF will only query one? In that case, which is "better" would depend on the use case. Or do you have another view design in mind?

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson, No the definition of a view becomes part of the execution plan and only databases/tables needed are accessed. i.e. if the query contains `WHERE [Database] = 'A'` only database 'A' will be accessed. Definition of a TVF is not part of the plan

Comment: @adrianm Cool, never tried cross database views, but that would indeed make them feasible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can do this by removing the reference to your database and schema

```
SELECT * FROM SERIES_DATA
```

It is a question of creating the schema in all your databases, and granting the login access to the databases and schemas (in this case you are using the default dbo schema).
If you are using the management studio, when you create logins, you can handle the rest with user mapping.
If you have the same schema (e.g. dbo), you can change your select to:

```
SELECT * FROM dbo.SERIES_DATA
```

You really don't want to include the database name unless you are joining tables across databases.